# Not able to connect to H2 database in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have the below in my yaml file.I keep getting the below error.how to resolve the below error.I am using latest spring boot version .

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database
> "C:/Users/mynname/test" not found, either pre-create it or allow
> remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments)
> [90149-214]

I can see the H2 console in http://localhost:8080/h2.But when i click on connect button i get the error.

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: create
```

Comment: how you are provind the url to connect on h2 console? Can you update the questing with this info?

Comment: I dont have any other configuration

Comment: I just want to start the H2.Create some tables while starting the Spring boot app.This is what i am trying to do

Comment: When you open h2 console on browser, you need to type the url to connect to the h2 database. How are you typing this on the input field? Are you typing exactly the value you provided on properties (jdbc:h2:mem:testdb)?

Comment: In console it shows jdbc:h2:mem:test

Comment: change it to: dbc:h2:mem:testdb and see if you can connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the h2 console change the default ur that appears there (jdbc:h2:mem:test) to jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
And you should be able to connect